# The screen isn't clearing the last text why?

Tags: c++, sfml

The text on screen isn't being replaced why?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main(){
  stringstream ss;
  sf::Font f;
  int mama = 212;
  sf::RenderWindow W(sf::VideoMode(640, 480) , "amama");
  W.setFramerateLimit(60);
  sf::Text text;

  if(!f.loadFromFile("arial.ttf")){

  }

  text.setFont(f);
  text.setColor(sf::Color::Red);

  while(W.isOpen()){
    sf::Event e;

    while(W.pollEvent(e)){
      switch(e.type){
        case sf::Event::Closed:
          W.close();
          break;
        case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
          if(e.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up){

            mama++;
            ss << mama;
            text.setString(ss.str());
          }
          break;
      }
    }

    W.draw(text);
    W.display();
    W.clear();

  }
}
```

The first time i call the text it shows ok.
But when i call it again the text isn't replaced it ust stays and 6 numbers apear and it doesn't clear it.Can you help me please?I am not that good at explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation

You'll need to clear the contents of your `std::stringstream ss` before inserting new data.

The current situation is that you first insert "212" (*mama*), then you insert "213" (incremented value of *mama*), making the contents of the `ss.str () == "212213"`.

<sup>**Note**: You should also call `W.clear ()` **before** you render a new frame (`W.display ()`), not after.</sup>

---

#### Proposed solution

Clear the contents of the *stringstream* prior to inserting new data, this can be done using [**ss.str ("")**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str):

```
if(e.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up){
   ss.str ("");               // set contents to that of an empty string
   mama++;
   ss << mama;                // insert new data
   text.setString(ss.str());
 }
```

If you are writing *C++11* the whole processes can be simplified by using [**`std::to_string`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), as in the below:

```
if(e.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up){
   text.setString(std::to_string (mama));
 }
```

Comment: alt. solution: create a *local* stream object.